# I can't numerically order the results of a GET request from Dynamo DB with Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to return data from a DynamoDB table with results ordered numerically by the Primary Sort Key. I am using a Lambda scan function to return the data but it is not returning in numerical order. 
The Primary Sort Key is 'time', how can i achieve this?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'eu-west-2', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {

    const params = {
        TableName: "finalTrickstar",

    };

    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            const items = data.Items.map(
                (dataField) => {

                  return {time: dataField.time.S, day: dataField.day.S, show: dataField.show.S, showID: dataField.showID.S};
               } 

                );
            callback(null, items);
        }
    });
    };
```

I thought having a Primary Sort Key would return results ordered by the key but instead they are seemingly not ordered at all.

Comment: Use `dynamodb.query` instead of a `scan` and add `ScanIndexForward: true` as a query param.

Comment: when i add them i get 
"errorType": "ValidationException",
  "errorMessage": "Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "Primary Sort Key" but DynamoDB supports two types of primary keys:

- partition key
- partition key + sort key (composite primary key)

If your table has a primary key composed of a partition key and a sort key then the data will be kept and retrieved sorted by the sort key. If the data type of the sort key is `Number`, the results are returned in numeric order; otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the `ScanIndexForward` parameter to false.

Make sure your table is configured correctly and that you're not expecting the data to be sorted in any other way than by the UTF-8 bytes of the sort key if it's not a number.

Comment: right, i have had numbers in as a string. so '10:00 - 11:00' for example. If i use ```Number``` instead of ```String``` then it works fine with ```scan```. Thanks